# Error while loading modules in test-kitchen

Tags: devops, test-kitchen

I am new to test kitchen and i am trying to use the existing vpc modules i have created earlier using terraform. I am having problems on loading the modules to test kitchen.

My folder structure looks like

```
tf_aws_cluster
├── .kitchen.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.md
│  ├── modules
|    |── vpc
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
|── variables.tf
```

the ~/tf_aws_cluster/.kitchen.yml file

```
---
driver:
  name: terraform

provisioner:
  name: terraform
  directory: ~/tf_aws_cluster/modules/vpc
  variable_files:
    - variables.tf
```

my ~/tf_aws_cluster/main.tf file looks like

```
module "vpc" {
  source         = "../modules/vpc"
  env            = "prod"
  aws_account_id = "************"
}
```

when i try to run

> bundle exec kitchen verify

i am getting an error in loading modules.

```
-----> Creating <default-ubuntu>...
       Copying configuration from "/home/ubuntu/tf_aws_cluster"...
       Upgrading modules...
       Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: module vpc: failed to get download URL for "../module/vpc": 200 OK resp:<!DOCTYPE html>
```

*what is the values i should pass under provisioner for the module ?*

I have tried by giving the full path for the  source parameter ~/tf_aws_cluster/main.tf

```
source         = "~/tf_aws_cluster/modules/vpc/"
```

this gives me an error as

```
Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: module vpc: invalid source string: ~/tf_aws_cluster/modules/vpc/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory should be a relative path in your `directory` attribute. Like this:

`directory: modules/vpc`

Also in the newly released [kitchen-terraform v3.0.0](https://github.com/newcontext-oss/kitchen-terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changed) you should be using `root_module_directory` instead of `directory`

---

On a related topic, I would recommend going through the [getting started](https://newcontext-oss.github.io/kitchen-terraform/getting_started.html) guide to help understand how to do test fixtures as that is what I think you are trying to accomplish with `main.tf` and `modules directory`.

I would organize the code as such:

```
tf_aws_cluster
├── .kitchen.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.md
│  ├── test
|    |── fixtures
|       |── my_module
│          ├── main.tf
│          └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
|── variables.tf
```

.kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: terraform
  directory: test/fixtures/my_module
  variable_files:
    - variables.tf

provisioner:
  name: terraform
```

the root main.tf:

```
# this should have your actual Terraform code
resource ... {
  ...
}
```

the test fixture main.tf (test/fixtures/my_module/main.tf)

```
# this should have a module reference to your root's main.tf such as:
module "vpc" {
  source         = "source = "../../.."
  env            = "prod"
  aws_account_id = "************"
}
```